# Nested list tail recursion on prolog

Tags: list, recursion, prolog

im trying to perform nested list tail recursion **without** using of built in `flatten` func

my example is sum of all values on the list

```
sum(LIST,SUM):-sum(LIST,0,SUM).
sum([],SUM,SUM).
sum([A|LIST],RES,SUM):-sum(A,RES2,SUM), RES1 is RES+RES2,sum(LIST,RES1,SUM).
sum([H|LIST],RES,SUM):-RES1 is RES+H,sum(LIST,RES1,SUM).
```

for example on flatten list

```
[trace] 13 ?- sum([1,2,3,4,5,6],Sum).
Sum = 21.
```

but if i try on nested list

```
[trace] 12 ?- sum([1,2,[3,4],5,6],Sum).
```

it's not workig

thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really strange that you get this sort of assignments without being taught the basics of how to go about solving them. And why do you need to reimplement library predicates?

You can look at the implementation of the [library predicate `flatten/2`](http://swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/home/vnc/prolog/lib/swipl/library/lists.pl?show=src#flatten/2). Note that it is deprecated. This is because, I cite, "Ending up needing `flatten/3` often indicates, like `append/3` for appending two lists, a bad design".

Even if you don't use `flatten/2`, it shows you how to deal with a nested list (which could indicate a bad design, but anyway).

```
sum_nested([], Sum, Sum) :- !.
sum_nested([X|Xs], Acc, Sum) :- !,
    sum_nested(X, 0, Sum_Nested),
    Acc1 is Acc + Sum_Nested,
    sum_nested(Xs, Acc1, Sum).
sum_nested(Number, Acc, Sum) :-
    Sum is Number + Acc.
```

You can't leave the cuts out if you want the predicate to succeed once. You also should notice that it is not strictly tail-recursive. Can you make it tail-recursive? What sort of input will cause the predicate to fail? What will happen if you have variables in the nested list?

Comment: thanks Boris ... so thare is no way to implement strictly tail-recursive nested list?

Comment: Every recursive algorithm can be transformed to be strict tail-recursive and from there iterative.

Comment: @avis If you can come up with a strict tail recursive version, you should post it as an answer to your question!

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `flatten` in a preprocessing step. Rename your `sum` to, for example, `sum_flatten`, and then add

```
sum(List, Sum) :- 
     flatten(List, FlattenList),
     sum_flatten(FlattenList, Sum).
```

Comment: yes .. im understand .. but i really want to implement that with no using of built in flatten func .. thanks

Comment: You should use `append/2` instead of flatten (available in SWI-Prolog at least), and while at it, also use `sum_list/2`: `append(Nested_List, List), sum_list(List, Sum)`

Answer (score 0):

a possible way to avoid flatten/2 it's to make a (sort of) member/2, like

```
leafs([E|L], R) :- !, (leafs(E, R) ; leafs(L, R)).
leafs(E, E) :- E \= [].
```

now library(aggregate) can serve like

```
sum(LIST, SUM) :- aggregate(sum(E), leafs(LIST, E), SUM).
```

giving

```
?- sum([1,[[2],3]],X).
X = 6.
```